# Make a sequence decrease to zero as fast as possible

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, optimization, computational-complexity

Fix $d>0$, and let $n$ be a positive integer going to infinity, and for $h>0$, define $E=E(n,h)$ by

$$
E(n,h) := h\sqrt{\log \frac{1}{h}} + \frac{1}{h}\sqrt{\frac{d\log n}{n}}.
$$

A strategy $h=h_n$ for selecting $h$ as a function of $n$ is called *admissible*, if the following conditions are respected:

- (i) $h_n \to 0$ in the limit $n \to \infty$, and
- (ii) $E(n,h_n) \to 0$ in the limit $n \to \infty$.

> **Question.** *What is a selection strategy $h=h_n$ which ensures that $E(n,h_n) \to 0$ as fast as possible ? In particular, is there a selection strategy for which $E$ decays asymptotically as rapidly as $1/n^{\alpha}$ (ignoring log factors), for some $\alpha \ge 1/2$ ?*

### Example

Just to be sure we're not searching in a vacuum, consider the following strategy
$$
h_n := \left(\dfrac{\log n}{n}\right)^s,
\tag{1}
$$
for $s > 0$, independent of $n$.
$$
\begin{split}
E(n, (1/n)\log n) &= s\left(\dfrac{\log n}{n}\right)^s (\sqrt{\log n} - \log\log n) + \left(\dfrac{n}{\log n}\right)^s\sqrt{\dfrac{d\log n}{n}}\\
& \asymp s\frac{(\log n)^{1/2+s}}{n^s} + \sqrt{d}\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)^{1/2-s}
\end{split}
$$

Thus, the strategy (1) is admissible if and only if $s \in (0,1/2)$.

Moreover, it is clear that the value of $s \in (0,1)$ which makes $E$ decrease to zero fastest is $s=1/2$. For this value of $s$, $E$ decreases to $0$ at the same rate as $n^{-1/4}$ (ignoring log terms),  which is short of the ultimate goal (namely $1/n^{1/2}$).

Comment: Can't just take a minimizer of $E(n,h)$?

Comment: I'd like to have an analytic solution, and I don't the minimizers of $E$ (over $h$) have analytic expression.

Comment: Also, I think the minimizer is $h=1$, which is not admissible. If I did not make a mistake, this just boils down to finding the slowest way of having $h\to 0$?

Comment: Hum, the slowest way of having $h \to 0$ might not even decrease $E$ to $0$ (and thus might not be admissible). No ? For example, take $h_n = (\log (n)/n)^s$ for $s \in (0,1)$. The slowest way to make this construction of $h_n$ go to $0$ is to take $s$ close to $0$; however, this would make $E$ go to $0$ arbitrarily slowly.

Comment: You've lost $\frac1{2}$ when transform $\sqrt{\log n}$ into power of $\log n$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Indeed, thanks. With the fix, my rate of decay in my suboptimal / dummy selection degrades from $1/n^{1/2}$ to  the much slower $1/n^{1/4}$ :(